# VisualStudio XAML designer tell me i need build 19041 but it's already installed

Tags: visual-studio, uwp-xaml

I'm creating a windows desktop universal app (UWP) using Windows Template Studio on Visual Studio 2019 Community, on a Windows 10 Family Edition.

Windows and VS2019 were updated today (before creating this app).

After the project was created using WTS i have an error telling me (mine is in french so i'll try my best to translate) that : *I need to upgrade to "windows 10, version 2004 (10.0.19041.0)" in order to display this content* (aka : the XAML UI designer). However, the 19041 sdk is already installed. I can build and run the application just fine. It only a problem with the designer.

If i change the application property target to from 19041 to *version 1903 (10.0 ; Build 18362)* and reload the project, it works just fine.

I don't think i really need this 19041 (i hope so) but : what's happening and how to fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the target version at 19041 (2004), this requires your development environment to be at least 19041. The SDK installed through Visual Studio contains some development tools corresponding to the platform, but UWP development usually requires some native resources (such as colors, control styles, etc.), and these resources will follow the system update.

So when you set the target version of the project to 19041, the target of some local resources referenced by the project is 19041. If your development environment is lower than this version, the designer will not be able to display.

Comment: mmm, the page tell me i can install it from VS2019, which i already did, so i'm confused now... BUT, at least i know why and what's happening so i can safely ignore it for now and deal with it when i'll need it. No need to target the very latest version for no reason :)